# I can't put a geopoint equal to null in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, resthighlevelclient

I have the code

```
 if(row.get("LATITUDE") != null && row.get("LONGITUDE") != null) {
            result.put("geoPoint", ImportUtils.getGeoPoint(row));}

 public static Map<String, Object> getGeoPoint(Map<String, Object> s) {
        Map<String, Object> r = new HashMap<>();
        BigDecimal lat = (BigDecimal) s.get("LATITUDE");
        BigDecimal lon = (BigDecimal) s.get("LONGITUDE");

        r.put("lat", lat.doubleValue());//широта -90/90
        r.put("lon", lon.doubleValue());//долгота -180/180
        return r;
    }
```

The problem is that if I do this, some objects don't have the geopoint field, but if I put null or put longitude and latitude as null, then there is a mapping error.

I want it to be like this if geopoint is null

```
"geopoint": {}, 
//or as a last resort
"geopoint" : null
```

Mapping

```
   },
        "geoPoint": {
          "type": "geo_point"

          }
```

I tried null_value: null, but for some reason it didn't work
How can I achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your mapping w/ `ignore_malformed`:

```
...
{
 "type" : "geo_point",
 "ignore_malformed" : true
}
...
```